# Not able to send entity object from Spring restcontroller as JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using spring restcontroller to send an entity as JSON object. I've added all necessary jar's

### My customer class

```
public class Customer  implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;
private String firstName;


public Customer(long id, String firstName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;     
}

public Customer() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}


}
```

### JARs added

commons-logging-1.2.jar, jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar, jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar, jackson-databind-2.9.0.jar, spring-aop,spring-core,spring-beans,spring-context, spring-expression, spring-web, spring-webmvc(all 4.3.9 version)

I don't have any xml configuration, its a pure annotation configuration. My code is

### AppConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.ifg.spring")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

### AppInitializer

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

}
```

### Customer model class

```
public class Customer  implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;
private String firstName;


public Customer(long id, String firstName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;     
}

public Customer() {
}

// setters and getters of id and name

}

@RestController
public class CustomerRestController {

@Autowired
private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@GetMapping("/customers/{id}")
public ResponseEntity getCustomer(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    System.out.println("Customer ID :"+id);         
    return new ResponseEntity(new Customer(101,"Aliya"), HttpStatus.OK);
}

}
```

Exception occurred is

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class net.qiib.spring.model.Customer
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class net.qiib.spring.model.Customer
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:187)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:203)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:113)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

P.S : I'm not using any XML configurations, only annotation config is used.

Comment: Show your getters, please

Comment: A message "No converter found for return value of type: class net.qiib.spring.model.Customer" says what you need. Have you read your stack trace before open a subject?  You have to set up a mapper with either data binding library. I used jackson, please check [this](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-jackson-demo) example

Comment: @slesh, you can see that I have the jackson jar in my code. I have added that to my build path

Comment: @Optio, updated with setters and getters

Comment: @Aily, of course, I see, but usually it is not enough, you need integrate these to your app by adding appropriate spring mapper beans, to be Spring learned about those.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SpringBoot. I sugest you to use this guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: Please, put more details on your answer. We can't rely only on external links, that might go offline in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Spring is saying to you it haven't found anything to transform your Java Class into Json.

Take a look on how to use Jackson and this kind of annotation : `@JsonTypeInfo(include = As.PROPERTY, property = "class", use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)`